# Implementing Binary Search using Java8 Streams API

Tags: java, java-8, binary-search

I would like to know whether is it possible to implement a binary search using the Java 8 Streams API? Binary search splits the array recursively before searching. Can we do the same using the Java 8 Streams API?

Comment: A stream is a possibly endless sequence of elements, one cannot simply split an endless sequence.

Comment: @Minn It is relatively rare for a stream to be endless. Also the nature of the algorithm already imposes significant constraints even if we start with an array.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are *finite*.  There is a well-defined start, middle and end to an array, and thus, binary search could suit this data structure well.

Streams are *infinite*.  You can stream across information from a network connection or from a streaming music service, and while there *may* be a well-defined start, there's an ill-defined middle or end since the stream could be interrupted abruptly or be made incomplete, or just go on for eternity.

Additionally, streams are uni-directional and cannot be recursed into.  Once you play an element of the stream, **it is lost** unless you cache it somewhere else locally (and we drift back towards finite data structures).

So, no.  You cannot use a binary search algorithm on a stream since you have no idea if what you're searching for has been played already or if it will be coming later.

Comment: I think the question is about implementing a binary search on an array using streams rather than the more traditional index based loops.

Comment: That's likely the case @BoristheSpider, but I stress that streams are not the new loop or recursive structure.  Streams serve a very specific purpose but, like most things in Java, can be retrofitted to suit different and sometimes inappropriate purposes.  Other tools and approaches exist if one wishes to perform a binary search.  Using a stream is not one of them.

Comment: I agree entirely - I just think the focus of this answer is not quite right.

Comment: Yes @BoristheSpider..i have an algo to find the out the missed value for a customer data.
Say a value missed in an array of values from 1...N+1

Right now i split the array into two halves and check the first array last value 
and its index diff is 1 ,,if so move to the right array and dot till i get only two values and then do the actual processing ..which is similar to binary search 


So instead of me doing this...i tot JAVA8 may have an api in the form of streams with me passing the functional implementation 
for any predefined functional interface .But doesnt think so

Comment: Not all streams are infinite. Many parallel algorithms (which the Java designers push) wouldn't work otherwise. Spliterator exists for a reason...

Comment: @wilmol:  [`Spliterator#trySplit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#trySplit--) seems to suggest otherwise in that it will continue to return values even in the context of an infinite stream.  The only real difference would be that *eventually* a finite split will return `null`, whereas an infinite split won't.

Answer (score 1):

You could call `BaseStream.spliterator` and use that to implement a binary search as if your code was part of the streams API, but it would be extremely inefficient for really obvious reasons.